# read-loop from TCP/IP

Tags: c#, tcp

I need to connect a server (with ip and port) and create a read-loop that will get messages from the server as XML. sometimes there are no messages from the server.

I tried to create a connection (works fine) and read messages, I get the first message from the server and when I'm trying to read another one - it get stuck. I think that maybe there are no messages right now but I need that the loop will continue until there will be messages... it doesn't even go to "catch" or "finally", just do nothing..

```
public class Connection
{
    public Connection()
    {
        Socket server = null;
        try
        {
            string p = string.Empty;
            using (var client = new TcpClient(myIPAddress, myPort))
            using (var stream = client.GetStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
               while (p != null)
               {
                    try
                    {
                        p = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                       //
                    }
               }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //
        }
        finally { 
            server.Close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions: where does it get stuck? what was sent, and what did you receive? did the sender end with a newline? did the sender have naggle enabled or disabled? is the sender perhaps waiting for anything from your code?

Comment: the first message was "hello" with a newline. when I tried to read another line (which maybe doesn't exist), it seems like I've got out of the function - all the variables' content disappears. I have  breakpoints in the catch and finally parts, but I never get there.

Comment: if the next line doesn't exist, and the caller hasn't closed their socket, then `ReadLine()` will block forever, sat waiting for data. Is that all this is about? There are two (normal) ways `ReadLine()` will exit: a) it managed to read a line of data (perhaps blocking for a while if necessary), returning the line of data, or b) the incoming stream was closed and no more data was found, returning `null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop **is** continuing, waiting for data. The issue here seems to be simply that `ReadLine()` is a blocking call. You mention that there might not be a message yet; well, `ReadLine()` is going to block until one of two conditions is met:

- it can successfully read some data, terminated by a newline (or EOF, i.e. a message without a newline followed by socket closure) - in which case it returns the line of data
- no more data is received **and** the stream is closed, in which case it returns `null`

So basically, `ReadLine()` is going to wait until either a message comes in, or the socket is closed. That is simply the behaviour of `ReadLine()`. If that is problematic, you could work closer to the socket, and check `NetworkStream.DataAvailable` **but**: note that only tells you if some data is **currently** available; it doesn't mean "this is an entire message", nor can it be used to tell if more messages *will* arrive. The main use of `DataAvailable` is to decide between sync and async access. Plus if you work close to the socket you'll have to do all your own buffering and encoding/decoding.

It looks to me like `ReadLine()` is working successfully. The only thing I would do here is re-phrase it a bit:

```
string line;
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
    // line is meaningful; do something
}
```

One last thought: xml is not always trivially split into messages simply on a "per-line" basis. You might want to consider some other form of framing, but that may well mean working closer to the socket, rather than a `StreamReader`.

Comment: I tried that now and again - when the program gets to the "while" loop  in the second time and try to read the second line- it gets stucked (or blocked..).. and nothing happens...

I don't have a problem to rewrite all my code if I need, I just don't know how and what to do.

Comment: @tamarg well, what do you **want** it to do, if there isn't a message and the socket is still open? waiting for a complete line (or stream closure) is the expected behaviour of ReadLine

Comment: hmm. I WANT to listen to a server that every 1-2 mintues sends me messages. I don't really care how to do it, I just want it to work! :(

Comment: wait - if there will be a new message now, the loop will continue?

Comment: @tamarg yes, as soon as a message *actually arrives*, `ReadLine()` will hand you the message for processing.

Comment: I don't get any messages..... maybe the problem is in the server, I'll try to ask the server's admin.

Comment: @tamarg have you tried a packet sniffer? to see what actually arrived?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12372/discussion-between-tamarg-and-marc-gravell)

Answer (score -2):

You have to wait till data arrives at the stream, you could try using follwing,

```
if(reader.EndOfStream)
   continue;
```

Comment: I didn't understand.... maybe now it's the end of the stream but next minute I'll have another message... I need to listen all the time and read new messages when they arrive..

Comment: Don't read the stream if above flag says its end of stream. When data arrives,the flag will be set to false so u can read  it that time.

Comment: but how will the reader know that new data had arrived if I didn't read anything because the flag was set to false?

Comment: That is rather pointless. The reader **already** waits for data, and besides... why would you `continue` if you are at the EOF?

Comment: if it is EOF, and i read data, it will stuck , so i dont want  that to happen, so rather i would conitnue so that i can read data when it comes. please check and post ur comments.

Comment: `EndOfStream` only happens in the condition that the socket is closed. In that condition, `ReadLine()` will **immediately** return `null`. This check does not achieve anything useful.

Comment: Not so,  Check out herer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.endofstream.aspx

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian please be very explicit: what part of that do you think supports your statement? 'cos I'm not seeing it. A NetworkStream only knows that it is EOF **once the socket is closed**.

Comment: -1, you don't know what you are talking about. Marc Gravell is correct. A network stream is not at the end until its closed.